# Not able scroll to input in ionic app when focus on input in phone

Tags: html, angularjs, css, ionic-framework

**Predefined phone functionality:** When we focus on any input it will automatically scroll to that input in mobile device.

**Problem:** Its not working in my ionic app, because of horizontal scroll also there, so when i click on input in mobile device, it is not scrolling automatically to that input and input hides behind the keyboard.

I have tried `delegate-handle` for this, but it's not working.

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/tPcYufQwDWNgI7zM14Ia?p=preview) for the same

HTML

```
<ion-scroll direction="xy" class="scroll" delegate-handle="nomineeDiv">
    <div class="table-row" ng-repeat="data in nominee"><!-- Multiple div show horizontally -->
        <form name="data.formName">
            <!-- Long vertical form
            .....
            .....
            after 4 input tags --> 
            <input type="text" name="something"/>
            <!-- Need to scroll to input when input focused -->
        </form>
    </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

Controller

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('nomineeDiv').scrollBy(580, 140, true);
```

Comment: Can you just verify i did it that is your way or not http://keepnote.cc/3331328

Comment: Ok. just check in device. i click on last input page is scroll up and focus comes. that textbox top side of keyboard.http://prntscr.com/entaf1

Comment: I check it like open application scroll vertical and click on last form textbox keyboard open but page is scroll and comes to start right? that is issue you face?

Comment: basically my input hides behind the keyboard, not scroll up on click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution.1** Can you try to create a double click event on which change the position of form to be static? That may take your footer to top position.

**Solution.2** Using CSS apply `overflow-y: scroll;` on the form.

**Solution.3** You can also try to remove preference `<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />` in config.xml file.

I had the same issue and I resolve it using **Solution.2**.

Here is a link -- [Keyboard Hiding Inputs Problem](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/365)

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by adding "scrollAssist: true" and "autoFocusAssist: true" to app.module in the `@ngModule`. Like this:

```
imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {scrollAssist: true, autoFocusAssist: true}), 
   ]
```

and add css on column like this

```
ion-col{
   position: initial !important;
}
```